# Multiple divs with same ID in revision history

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, design

When looking at the HTML source of an arbitrary [revision history page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3418472/revisions), I noticed that there are multiple `div`s with ID `question`.

To [recapitulate](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2),

> **id** = [*name*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) [[CS]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#case-sensitive)
>  This attribute assigns a name to an
>   element. *This name must be unique in a
>   document.*

So, why are there multiple `div`s with the same ID on these pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These IDs are now revision guids themselves, no more conflict!